# How can I specify the types of two keys separately in a Typescript generic?

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a "group-by-and-sum" function over Javascript objects:

```
function groupBySum<
  GroupByKey extends string,
  SumKey extends string,
  Record extends ???
>(groupBy: GroupByKey, sumOver: SumKey, records: Record[]): Map<R[GroupByKey], number>{
   ...
}
```

I should be able to call it like this:

```
>> groupBySum('color', 'age', cats)
Map('black' => 3, 'orange' => 2, 'white' => 4)
```

The `groupBy` property can be any type, but the `sumOver` property must be a number.

What is the type of `Record` here? (Or, more generally, how should I define these generic types?)

(I'm sure this has been asked before but I'm not sure how to express myself in the proper terminology here.)

Comment: Can you include `cats` map and some other test cases that we can take as a reference during testing?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N95b1N) meet your needs?  If so, I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yep, I think the `{ ... } & { ... }` syntax is what I was missing here. That works!

Comment: Guess I don’t need to write this up since @wonderflame already did ‍♂️

Comment: @jcalz apologies, was doing in parallel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result by constraining `Record` to be an object with the key of `GroupByKey` with any value and key `SumKey` with the `number` type:

```
function groupBySum<
  GroupByKey extends string,
  SumKey extends string,
  Rec extends Record<GroupByKey, unknown> & Record<SumKey, number>,
>(
  groupBy: GroupByKey,
  sumOver: SumKey,
  records: Rec[],
): Map<Rec[GroupByKey], number> {
   // ...;
}
```

Note that `Record` is preserved type therefore I renamed the generic parameter to `Rec`.

This implementation insures that both `groupBy` and `sumOver` exist in the items of the passed `records`.

```
const cats = [
  {
    color: 'black',
    age: 3,
    notNumber: 'das',
  },
  {
    color: 'orange',
    age: 2,
    notNumber: 'das',
  },
  {
    color: 'white',
    age: 4,
    notNumber: 'das',
  },
];

// no error expected
groupBySum('color', 'age', cats);

// error expected
groupBySum('color', 'notNumber', cats);

// error expected
groupBySum('invalidGroupBy', 'age', cats);
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwE5xABwEIE8DKIAtgDwCwAUIogOLpZ4DSAproswB5TNgAmAzon5RUMMMgA0laoSIs2nbn0HDR4qVUQAlZhHZceA7bripeJOhhy55ExOADWYOAHcwAPkQAyYxFPnZW0QwYgAjZlR3DXcACmkUemsALlpEplYNan5iAHkANwiUwIz41BMzfhSdCABtAF0NAEoUgFkAQ0wSaprLBhtWBuCwiM8Ab1LmKBBUJFGAX0Q2wTawXABuSjnKSj8wYUQINqhBAF5EGvjxzWo-ABtTFIByUNu2iAdHzOpF5GYUgGYvtRnFAAHLDVBPXhLT7xOZfK7fA5we6QxCPUwrX6w64-P6IABMQOCcDBEKhMK+8Mu8RuKIe6JcAAsYNwcUi2r8UgAWYkg8FEcJox7Q-jsxDUih1DYUSgAejlJPYqHQqH0mF03F4lDQVjwshijzupk+6M5zFNh2OjRl8sVEVV6s1zG1FF1fQNRvpqFNj35EMtR34Nu2FAVysdnA10BdOrSBGIhrEeTatxgvF61l95sD1plQA)